# NoMethodError: undefined method `JWTAsserter' for Google::APIClient:Class with google-api-client v0.5.0

Tags: google-api

I am trying to authorise an application-owned (service) user. I do this in the console:

```
client = Google::APIClient.new
key = Google::APIClient::PKCS12.load_key('/path/to/privatekey.p12', 'notasecret')
service_account = Google::APIClient::JWTAsserter('me@developer.gserviceaccount.com','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction',key)
```

The last step fails with:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `JWTAsserter' for Google::APIClient:Class

I see there was a similar problem reported in versions < 0.44 but I am on v 0.5.0

Comment: My bad. Should be Google::APIClient::JWTAsserter.new(...)